# MsBuild SDK project style: project dependencies sometimes fails

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, .net-standard-2.0, msbuild-target

In the solution I have some dependent project configured as SDK style projects:

- Proj A responsible for doing some routine as MsBuild task
- Proj B project which requires such processing for compiling correctly
- Task is configured at Proj B as MsBuild target with attribute BeforeTargets="CoreCompile".

Based on that Proj A should be fully compiled before running task on Proj B compilation.
Both projects has different compilation target (NetStandard20 and Net462). Therefore I couldn't make a direct reference but do solution-wide project dependency with setting property AddSyntheticProjectReferencesForSolutionDependencies as false (otherwise msbuild tries to make project dependency forcible).

In that setup, MsBuild sometimes fails on compilation: Proj A started to compile but haven't finished in time when Proj B run the task.
MSBuild is started on CI machine with key /m.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you actually do want a synthetic project reference but there is a subtle issue in MSBuild at the moment that creates some issues across project references if the project having the dependency is multi-targeting. This is [fixed in 15.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/3628).

Please try it out in the visual studio preview version of 15.9 (at the time of writing: 15.9 Preview 2).

If you don't want to wait, you can add a similar project reference in the csproj file yourself:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\other\project.csproj"
    ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
    LinkLibraryDependencies="false"
    CopyLocal="false"
    SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties="true"
    GlobalPropertiesToRemove="TargetFramework"
    />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, such project dependency works for me. I also met with situation that VS with SDK projects (solution with about 150 projects) consume twice more memory (2.5Gb against 1.2Gb in classic style). Do you know by chance is any tricks exist to decrease it or it would be improved in nearest future?

Comment: I don't, but do file an issue at http://github.com/dotnet/project-system and see if one of the project system team members can help you

Comment: I have tried it on production and got warning icon for such references. I assume it because project targets are different. Do you know any property to ignore warnings for the artificial references?

Comment: I have found that adding ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" lead to warning error but still haven't found the solution for hiding it.

Comment: Link to the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2928